# How to change the python string substring information

Tags: python, string, binary

I have 1 `bitsInfo` string:

```
bitsInfo="0100001111110001"
```

and 1 array `bitReplace` which includes subarray:

```
bitReplace=[["1","5","00000"],["8","11","0000"]]
```

The first element of the subarray is `startbit` location and the second element is the `endbit` location.

The goal of the script is to replace the `bitsInfo` string (with the third element of subarray) base on `startbit` and `endbit` information.

The expected result should be

```
bitsFinal="0000001100000001"
```

I have tried this method:

```
for bits in bitReplace:
    bitsFinal = bits[:int(bits[0])+bits[2]+ bits[int(bits[1]+1:]
```

This method doesn't really work. May I know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are close but you are not using the original string anywhere. Try this:

```
bitsFinal = bitsInfo
for bits in bitReplace:
     bitsFinal = bitsFinal[:int(bits[0])] + bits[2] + bitsFinal[int(bits[1])+1:]
```

the result is:

```
>>> bitsFinal
'0000001100000001'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for bits in bitReplace:
  bitsFinal = bits[:int(bits[0])]+bits[2]+ bits[int(bits[1])+1:]
```

I think there are problems with parantheses.

Comment: Not a complete answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).